# extern "C": What does and what doesn't need it?

Tags: c++, c, header-files

There are already questions about `extern "C"` on functions, but this question tries to extend it to other things such as variables and more.

If I have a `foo.hpp` header to use a `foo.c` file from C++, I made this template which I filled with simple examples for this question:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard { ******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <cstdbool>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>


/******************************************************************************
 ******* typedefs *************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/* `#if !defined(UINT128_MAX)` is to test if uint128_t already exists */
#if !defined(UINT128_MAX)
    typedef __uint128_t uint128_t;
    typedef __int128_t  int128_t;
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#if !defined(UINT128_MAX)
    #define UINT128_MAX (~((uint128_t)0))
#endif
#if !defined(INT128_MAX)
    #define INT128_MAX  ((int128_t)(UINT128_MAX >> 1))
#endif
#if !defined(INT128_MIN)
    #define INT128_MIN  ((int128_t)(-INT128_MAX - 1))
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enums ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
enum    Some_Enum {
    SOME_CONSTANT_A,
    SOME_CONSTANT_B,

    SOME_CONSTANT_C
};


/******************************************************************************
 ******* structs / unions *****************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
union   Some_Union {
    int128_t    a;
    int64_t     b[SOME_CONSTANT_C];
};

struct  Some_Struct {
    union Some_Union    a;
    bool                b;
};


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static const variables ***********************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
static const    struct Some_Struct  x = {
    .a  = {
        .b  = {
            [SOME_CONSTANT_A]   = 0,
            [SOME_CONSTANT_B]   = 1
        }
    },
    .b  = true
};


/******************************************************************************
 ******* C wrapper { **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
extern  "C" {


/******************************************************************************
 ******* extern variables *****************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
extern  union Some_Union    y;


/******************************************************************************
 ******* extern functions *****************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
int foo(size_t n, int128_t arr[restrict]);


/******************************************************************************
 ******* } C wrapper **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
}   /* extern "C" */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static inline functions (prototypes) *********************************
 ******************************************************************************/
static inline   int compare_ldbl(const void *a_p, const void *b_p);


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static inline functions (definitions) ********************************
 ******************************************************************************/
static inline   int compare_ldbl(const void *a_p, const void *b_p)
{
    long double a = *(long double *)a_p;
    long double b = *(long double *)b_p;

    if (a < b)
        return  -1;
    else if (a > b)
        return  1;
    else
        return  0;
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******* } include guard ******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#endif      /* foo.hpp */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

All the types, macros, `enum`s, `struct`s, `union`s, and `extern` variables and functions should be compatible with C (as much as possible).  Only `static` things can behave different, because I can tune them for C++ just in the header.

Is that the correct place to put the C wrapper?

Comment: Don't variables have name mangling?  I'm sorry but my knowledge of C++ is close to 0.

Comment: By the way, you use some C-specific stuff in that header file. Designated initializers for structure members is coming in the next version of the C++ standard (C++20). And designated array initializers aren't part of C++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern "C"` declares a function type, function, or variable to have C language linkage [[dcl.link]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.link#1). You need `extern "C"` if you want to make a function or variable defined in your C++ code usable for C code, or if you want to make your C++ code use a function or variable that is defined in C code. That's it. This is basically all the C++ language has to say about the matter.

Contrary to popular belief, the purpose of `extern "C"` *is not* to inhibit name mangling. Name mangling is not a concept that exists in the C++ language and, therefore, there cannot possibly be a way to explicitly control it from within the C++ language. Name mangling is a mechanism employed by many (basically all) C++ implementations when they map your C++ code to a given target platform. It's an implementation detail. The purpose of `extern "C"` is to instruct the compiler to do whatever it is that needs to be done to make the given entities link with C code on the target platform. With many ABIs, that implies no name mangling. But with some ABIs, e.g., [the Windows ABI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/name-decoration?view=vs-2017), even C functions are subject to name mangling (in this particular case due to the presence of different calling conventions). Use `extern "C"` when you want to link C++ code with C code. That's its purpose and that's all it's good for. If you want to control the names of exported or imported symbols, use whatever is the way to do so according to the documentation of your toolchain for the given target platform, which will typically be stuff like [Module Definition Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files?view=vs-2017), linker flags, …

Comment: "Use `extern "C"` when you want to link C++ code with C code": I understand that as: "Put everything inside `extern "C"`". Do you mean that? I separated sections of code to know if all/some of them should go inside the wrapper.

Comment: Language linkage only applies to function types, and functions and variables with external linkage (effectively, global functions and extern global variables). `extern "C"` doesn't have an effect on anything else. As far as I'm aware, the sole reason behind the typical approach of just wrapping the content of an entire header in an `extern "C" { … }` specification is just to avoid having to explicitly type `extern "C"` in front of all the individual functions/variables that would be affected…

Comment: Since the C ABI is the defacto lingua franca on many platforms, the `extern "C"` may be an ABI bridge between C++ and other languages, too, besides C.  Other concerns deal with exception handling over the C barrier.  A lot depends on your platform's toolchain.  It will likely be a point of concern for portability (if that is a concern at all for your project).

Answer (score 6):

While it does other things as well, the main point about `extern "C"` is to inhibit [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

And name mangling is mainly needed for two things:

1. Overloading of functions
2. Allowing symbols with the same name in different scopes

Since all global (non-namespace) structures, enumeration, types and variables can't be overloaded they don't need name mangling and therefore don't need `extern "C"`. It's really only needed for global (non-namespace) functions.

Comment: As C doesn't have namespaces, and `extern "C" {}` is only for C (AFAIK), that would mean it is needed and only needed for extern functions defined in C code, right?

Comment: No, @CacahueteFrito, it is for *all* functions that are or must be callable from C, whether defined and written in C or in C++ or in some other language.

Comment: Right, I forgot about functions written in C++ and callable from C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Those functions need to be in global namespace in C++, or can they be in a namespace?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito C doesn't have namespaces, so you don't need `extern "C"` for them (as they won't be callable from C anyway).